# Can't rm object in R?

Tags: r

In my console ,i can not delete objects ,why?

```
> ls()
[1] "f1"      "f2"      "getmail" "k"       "mail"    "pattern" "rm"      "word"    "x"      
> rm(k)
Error in rm(k) : unused argument(s) (k)
> rm("k")
Error in rm("k") : unused argument(s) ("k")
```

Comment: You have an object `rm` listed, is it a function? try `base::rm(k)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have overwritten the `rm` object with an own object called `rm`:

> ```
> > ls()
> [1] "f1"      "f2"      "getmail" "k"       "mail"    "pattern" "rm"      "word"    "x"
> ```

So when you write `rm(something)` it’s not calling the original `rm` but your own. To call the original `rm`, use

```
originalRm <- get('rm', baseenv())
originalRm(object)

# or, simpler:

base::rm(object)
```

Comment: The very last part of circle 8 of the R Inferno suggests running 'conflicts()' when "you are getting results that are totally at odds with your expectations" in order to "look where you are stepping"...